# How to disable base64 image to url conversion in Odoo?

Tags: python, odoo, base64

I use **email_template.xml** in odoo 16:

```
      <field name="body_html">
        <![CDATA[
        <div style="background-color: #333; color: white; padding: 25px">
          <t t-out="object.logo_html"/>
        </div>
        ]]>
      </field>
```

and my **email_template.py**:

```
class EmailTemplateTest(models.Model):
    _name = "module.test.email.template"  
    logo_html = fields.Char("logo", compute="_compute_logo_html")


    def _compute_logo_html(self):
        for test in self:
            test.logo_html = '<img data-file-name="image.png" src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUg..." />'
```

**In mail, i get html but my base64 code convert to url:**

```
<img src="http://localhost:8069/web/image/260?access_token=646c73ba-d0c7-45ef-8656-c8246a321d92" alt="image0">
```

I've spent a lot of time trying to figure out why it works like that, but I can't find it.
I would like to disable this feature because my odoo is a private network that no one has access to.
And the images are sent exactly to odoo, to some temporary storage.

****this** behavior is observed even if I explicitly specify base64 in the XML without using python.*

Maybe someone has faced this, I will be grateful for help.
I keep looking for solutions.

[odoo github repo](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/638b61114d8148557cdbcc30a1272e1b3da79880/addons/im_livechat/data/mail_templates.xml#L44)

I tried to insert an image like it is used for example in github odoo, but then I saw that there is also a url instead of base64 :C

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix the problem, not sure if this is a fix, more likely a bug that can be used as a feature

my **email_template.py**:

```
class EmailTemplateTest(models.Model):
_name = "module.test.email.template"  
logo_html = fields.Html("logo", compute="_compute_logo_html")


def _compute_logo_html(self):
    for test in self:
        test.logo_html = """
            <img src="data:image/png;base64, iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAQQAAAA4CAYAAAAbx4...."> 
        """
```

And my **email_template.xml**:

```
 <field name="body_html">
    <![CDATA[
    <div style="background-color: #333; color: white; padding: 25px">
      <t t-out="object.logo_html"/>
    </div>
    ]]>
  </field>
```

After such manipulations, Odoo stopped converting my base64 into some kind of url, and sent the email exactly with the inserted base64 img.